# Vba -excel .Formula method is slow

Tags: excel, vba

What's wrong with the below code? I am trying to `vlookup` with closed data from another workbook. If I run this code it takes a long time to execute. Finally it hangs ... but it produces the correct result eventually:

```
Sub testing()
  Range("G1").EntireColumn.Insert
  With Range("G2")
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F2,'C:\Users\sathisk\Desktop\Macros\ReferencePath\[HUL_Assets_18th April 2012.xls]HUL_Assets_18th April 2012.xls'!A$1:J$65536,10,0)"
    .Copy
    .Offset(0, -1).Select
  End With

  Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Select

  With ActiveCell
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    .Copy
    .Select
  End With

  Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlUp)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
Option Explicit

Sub testing()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Range("G1").EntireColumn.Insert

    LastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Range("G2:G" & LastRow)
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F2,'C:\Users\sathisk\Desktop\Macros\ReferencePath\[HUL_Assets_18th April 2012.xls]HUL_Assets_18th April 2012.xls'!A$1:J$65536,10,0)"
    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

I would also recommend you to change `J$65536` to the actual last row in that sheet. For example if in that sheet the data is till row 1000 then change it to `J$1000`

Comment: :) Thanks For the code Siddharth .. Reason why am using range J$65536  .. Vloopup pick the data from closed workbook .. Which the workbook changes(increase and decrease) d rows day by day ..

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Siddharth recommendation I would also add

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turn off screen updating to speed up process.
    at the top of the macro along with
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

then add 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turn on screen updating.
    at the bottom along with
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

I use both methods to free up the CPU to just running the macro's, no screen updates or calculating until macro is finished.